# Proof involving Floor function

Tags: proof-writing, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Prove: $\forall l \in \mathbb{Z}: \forall r \in \mathbb{R}: 0 \le r \lt 1 \Rightarrow\lfloor l+r\rfloor = l$

My attempt:

Let: $l \in \mathbb{Z}, r \in \mathbb{R}.$

Assume: $0 \le r \lt 1.$

$\lfloor l + r \rfloor \le \lfloor l \rfloor + \lfloor r \rfloor = \lfloor l \rfloor + 0$, since $0 \le r \lt 1$.

$\lfloor l \rfloor + 0 = l$, since $l \in \mathbb{Z}$

Is that correct? This is for a beginners' proofs course.

Comment: An approach you could take is to show that $l \leq (l +r) < l+1$

Comment: Your approach is totally right.

Comment: you've not proved $l\le\lfloor l+r\rfloor$

Comment: @JonMarkPerry if I change the <= sign to an = sign, would the proof be correct? i.e. $\lfloor l + r \rfloor = \lfloor l \rfloor + \lfloor r \rfloor = ... $

Comment: no, but you can say $\lfloor l \rfloor \le \lfloor l+r \rfloor \le \lfloor l \rfloor + \lfloor r \rfloor$

Comment: What is the definition/properties of $\;\lfloor \cdots \rfloor\;$ that you are given / may use?

Comment: @MarnixKlooster

Assumptions 1: $$\forall x \in R: \lfloor x \rfloor \in Z  \wedge  \lfloor x \rfloor \le x  \wedge  [\forall z \in Z: z \le x \Rightarrow z \le \lfloor x \rfloor]$$

Assmpt. 2: $$\forall x \in R: \forall y \in Z: [y \le x  \wedge  [\forall z \in Z: z \le x \Rightarrow z \le y]] \Rightarrow y = \lfloor x \rfloor$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correctness depends on the properties of $\;\lfloor \cdots \rfloor\;$ that you are allowed to use.  Since you gave none, let me use the following definition: for every real $\;x, y\;$,
$$
\tag{0}
\lfloor x \rfloor = y \;\;\equiv\;\; 0 \le x - y \lt 1 \;\land\; y \in \mathbb Z
$$

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\when}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
$Now, for any real $\;l,r\;$, let's see if we can use this definition to simplify $\;\lfloor l + r \rfloor = l\;$:
$$\calc
    \tag 1
    \lfloor l + r \rfloor = l
\op=\hint{definition $\ref 0$ with $\;x,y := l+r, l\;$}
    0 \le l+r - l \lt 1 \;\land\; l \in \mathbb Z
\op=\hint{arithmetic: simplify}
    \tag 2
    0 \le r \lt 1 \;\land\; l \in \mathbb Z
\endcalc$$
This immediately proves the original statement, which says that $\ref 2$ implies $\ref 1$.

---

*Update.* In the comments you now specified that, instead, your basic properties/assumptions are the following, for real $\;x\;$ and for $\;n \in \mathbb Z\;$:
\begin{align}
\tag{A1a}
& \lfloor x \rfloor \in \mathbb Z  \\
\tag{A1b}
& \lfloor x \rfloor \le x  \\
\tag{A1c}
& n \le x \;\then\; n \le \lfloor x \rfloor \\
\tag{A2}
& n \le x  \land \langle \forall z : z \in \mathbb Z : z \le x \then z \le n \rangle \;\then\; n = \lfloor x \rfloor
\end{align}
(Apologies for switching to a slightly different notation, which I am more used to, and which I feel focuses on the essentials. See [EWD1300](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html) for more details.)

Now one way to prove the original statement, is to again start with the main part that we're to prove:
$$\calc
    \lfloor l + r \rfloor = l
\op\when\hints{using $\ref{A2}$ using $\;l \in \mathbb Z\;$}
        \hint{-- this seems the only assumption directly applicable}
    l \le l + r  \;\land\; \langle \forall z : z \in \mathbb Z : z \le l + r \then z \le l \rangle
\op=\hint{LHS: simplify by subtracting $\;l\;$; RHS: substitute $\;z := z + l\;$}
    0 \le r  \;\land\; \langle \forall z : z \in \mathbb Z : z + l \le l + r \then z + l \le l \rangle
\op=\hint{RHS: simplify by subtracting $\;l\;$; contraposition}
    0 \le r  \;\land\; \langle \forall z : z \in \mathbb Z : z \gt 0 \then z \gt r \rangle
\op=\hint{RHS: ordering}
    0 \le r  \;\land\; r < 1
\endcalc$$
Note that we did not need to use any part of assumption 1.

---

Now you should try to take the proof from your question, together with Jon Mark Perry's suggestion, and write it in the above format: this forces you to add an explicit justification for each step.

However, be warned that the property $\;\lfloor x + y \rfloor \;\le\; \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor\;$ does *not* hold in general for all real $\;x,y\;$: e.g., $\;\lfloor \tfrac 1 2 + \tfrac 1 2 \rfloor \;=\; 1 \;>\; 0 \;=\; \lfloor \tfrac 1 2 \rfloor + \lfloor \tfrac 1 2 \rfloor\;$.  Instead property $\ref 5$ below *does* hold.

Also, note that you would only be allowed to use the following properties, if you can prove them from $\ref{A1a}$, $\ref{A1b}$, $\ref{A1c}$, and $\ref{A2}$, for real $\;x,y\;$ and $\;n \in \mathbb Z\;$:
\begin{align}
\tag{3} & \lfloor n \rfloor \;=\; n \\
\tag{4} & x \le y \;\then\; \lfloor x \rfloor \le \lfloor y \rfloor \\
\tag{5} & \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor \;\le\; \lfloor x + y \rfloor \\
\tag{6} & 0 \le x \lt 1 \;\then\; \lfloor x \rfloor = 0 \\
\end{align}

Comment: Assmpt. 1: $$\forall x \in R: \lfloor x \rfloor \in Z  \wedge  \lfloor x \rfloor \le x  \wedge  [\forall z \in Z: z \le x \Rightarrow z \le \lfloor x \rfloor]$$

Assmpt. 2: $$\forall x \in R: \forall y \in Z: [y \le x  \wedge  [\forall z \in Z: z \le x \Rightarrow z \le y]] \Rightarrow y = \lfloor x \rfloor$$

I basically showed that l+r = x and l = y = z. Then I "brought in" the assumption into the proof and showed that y = l = $\lfloor$ x $\rfloor$ = $\lfloor$ l + r $\rfloor$. Does that sound right?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=l+r$. Since $r \ge 0$ we have $l \le l+r=x$ and, since $r<1$ we have $x=l+r<l+r+(1-r)=l+1$.

Now use the fact that:
$$
\forall l \in \mathbb{Z} \qquad \lfloor x \rfloor=l \iff l\le x\lt l+1
$$
that can be easily proved by the definition:

$$
\lfloor x \rfloor= \mbox{Max}\{n\in \mathbb{Z}, n\le x \}
$$

Comment: If the OP wants to use the fact that you gave, then I'd suggest to use it directly, by writing down your proof as follows:$\newcommand{\Xop}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}} \newcommand{\Xhi}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }$ for every $\;l \in \mathbb Z\;$ and real $\;r\;$,$$\begin{align} \quad &\lfloor l + r \rfloor = l\Xop=\Xhi{using your fact, and the assumption that $\;l \in \mathbb Z\;$}l \le l+r \lt l+1\Xop=\Xhi{arithmetic: simplify by subtracting $\;l\;$}0 \le r \lt 1\end{align}$$